# Difference between printwritter and BufferedReader for Java server sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Wanted to know with java sockets whats the difference between the two. Trying to understand how to make a java server socket code using lessons from oracle and this is what it shows at the momment on their tutorials

```
int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

try ( 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    PrintWriter out =
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
) {
```

Comment: Well a *writer* is for *writing* data, and a *reader* is for *reading* data. That's the first and biggest difference between them...

Comment: So the writer..will write data from server to client?

Comment: Yes, when it's server code. At the client side, the writer will write from the client to the server...

Comment: That code is executed on the server. The `accept` means that the operating system will patch a client request through to the waiting code, and gives the clientSocket to write with a PrintWriter to the client.

Comment: InputStreamReader and PrintWriter also have versions where you can explicitly specify the character encoding. Otherwise the computer's encoding is taken, and there is a server and a different client, that could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

-Reader and -Writers are character-based and streams are byte-based.

In your example. You use writer when you want to write something to the socket and reader when you read something from the socket.

Hank